# Simple Sql Query to Hibernate Query

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

This is my sql query, how can i write this on hibernate? There is a 'many to many' relation.

```
SELECT * 
FROM icerik AS i 
LEFT JOIN yazi_kategori AS yk 
ON i.YAZI_ID = yk.YAZI_ID 
LEFT JOIN kategori AS k ON yk.KATEGORI_ID = k.KATEGORI_ID
WHERE yk.KATEGORI_ID = 1;
```

> icerik table has=> icerikid yazi_kategori has => icerikid , kategoriid
>   kategori table has => kategoriid

Answer (score 0):

your criteria will like:

```
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Icerik.class, "i");
    criteria.createAlias('i.yazi_kategori', 'yk', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
    criteria.createAlias('i.kategori', 'k', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq('i.KATEGORI_ID', 1));
    criteria.list()
```